# Python: urllib2.open() is slow, need a faster way to download files

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I need to download many Tiles from a OpenStreepMap-Tileserver in a python script. Each Tile has his own URL. There is a constant part of the URL (`"http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/..."`) and a dynamic part described by the zoomlevel and the x- & y-Coordinate of a Tile (`".../zoomlevel/x/y.png"`). [Here](http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/18/136933/86273.png) is an example.

At the moment, I use urllib2 to download the Tiles. For more efficiency, I parallelized the tile download. Anyway, it takes 12 minutes in average to download 10.000 Tiles (that corresponds to only 40 Megabytes). I figgured out, that the function urllib2.urlopen(url) needs sometimes many seconds (10 till 20 seconds) to establish a connection to the OSM-Server. Is there another way, to download files from a HTTP Server or to speed up the connection establishment?

Answer (score 0):

You can download only a part by seting the Range header

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (start, end)
file = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Download the first half and start an other tread to download the other part

Example:

```
import urllib, urllib2
from thread import start_new_thread
def dwl1():
    url = "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/18/136933/86273.png" #url
    req = urllib2.Request(url) #http request.
    req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (0, 4836)
    img_part1 = urllib2.urlopen(req)

def dwl2():
    url = "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/18/136933/86273.png" #url
    req = urllib2.Request(url) #http request.
    req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (4836, 10000)
    img_part2 = urllib2.urlopen(req)
start_new_thread(dwl1)
start_new_thread(dwl2)
```

now bring part 1 and two together...
I'm pretty sure that it won't work, but you're searching somethig like that